# Moving a row from one table to another (Insert value list does not match column list)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, laravel

I am using Laravel PHP framework's Fluent query builder to move rows from one table to another. PDO is being used. While using the raw query `DB::query()`, I get the error:

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 
1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

SQL: INSERT IGNORE into listings_archive VALUES (?, ?)
```

**Query**

```
// Get rows from first table
$rows = DB::table('table_1')
        ->where('id', '>', '12345')
        ->get();

// Copy rows to second table
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $listing = get_object_vars($row);
    DB::query('INSERT IGNORE into table_2 VALUES (?, ?)', $row);
}
```

**var_dump of $row**

```
array(39) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "2511877"
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "AB"
    ["color"]=>
    NULL
    ["type"]=>
    NULL
    ...
```

What is causing the error and how can it be fixed? I tried removing the elements with `NULL`s but still get the same error!

---

### UPDATE

This is possibly a problem with the array being passed into `DB::query()`. These very simple example gave similar errors:

```
$row = array('id', 123);
DB::query('INSERT IGNORE into table_2 VALUES (?, ?)', $row);
```

and

```
$row = array('id' => 123);
DB::query('INSERT IGNORE into table_2 VALUES (?, ?)', $row);
```

**Error**

```
SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 
1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the column count doesn't match the number of values.
If you don't specify which columns, it defaults to all, so you want something like

```
Insert IGNORE into table_2(Column1,Column2) Values (?, ?)
```

Column1, Column2, being the names of the two columns in table_2 you want to put the values from Table_1 into.

Comment: Its probably a problem with the array that is passed into `DB::query()`. I tried a simple example but still does not work

Comment: Ah that means you are going to have to construct an array from $row. Any particular reason why you aren't just doing this with one sql statement instead of using PHP as a middleman?

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the problem. The usage of the function stated in the docs (http://laravel.com/docs/database/raw) had its syntax wrong, and should have included the columns just like what you have suggested.

Comment: Do you mean to move the rows directly from `table_1` to `table_2`? If so, how should it be done using MySQL only?

Comment: Sure the basic form is Insert Into Table1(Column1,Column2) Select OtherColumn1, OtherColumn2 From Table2. If you need something more complex, like skip existing values. Ask another question and supply the table schemas and mention waht constitutes an existing record

Answer (score 0):

Had the same Error msg, but i  used mysqli in php

- basically as stated above, if tables not identical in structure, you gotta name the fields

Solved by some tinkering:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO table2
                              (field1, field2, ..., )
                              SELECT
                              field1, field2, ..., 
                              FROM
                              table1 WHERE field = ? ");
```