# MySQL Insert :: MAX(FIELD)+1 - if null

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Moving a row from one table to another (Insert value list does not match column list)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12624511/moving-a-row-from-one-table-to-another-insert-value-list-does-not-match-column)

For one of my inserts I have the following: (PDO / MySQL)

```
   $this->sql = "INSERT INTO tblfixedfares NULL, SELECT NULL, IFNULL(MAX(FixedFareId), 0) + 1, '$fieldFrompc', '$fieldTopc', '$fieldDay', '1', 'Car') FROM tblfixedfares;
                    INSERT INTO tblfixedfares NULL, SELECT NULL, IFNULL(MAX(FixedFareId), 0) + 1, '$fieldFrompc', '$fieldTopc', '$fieldNight', '2', 'Car') FROM tblfixedfares;";
```

Basically, this is not working as it is not inserting a value for `FixedFareId`.

What I want to do is set the FixedFareId to 1 greater than the highest fixed fare id value, and if it is null to set the FixedFareId to 1.

Not sure what exactly is the problem with the code but I can see it is not picking up anything for the FixedFareId as I get following response:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[21S01]: Insert value list does not match column list: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1SQL

INSERT INTO tblfixedfares VALUES (NULL, 'le675', 'le115', '11', '1', 'Car');
INSERT INTO tblfixedfares VALUES (NULL, 'le675', 'le115', '22', '2', 'Car');
```

Basically two inserts happen in a single query, if there is nothing in the database FixedFareId needs to be 1:

So the first insert needs to be:

```
INSERT INTO tblfixedfares VALUES (NULL, **1**, 'le675', 'le115', '11', '1', 'Car');
INSERT INTO tblfixedfares VALUES (NULL, **1**, 'le675', 'le115', '22', '2', 'Car');
```

the next insert would be:

```
INSERT INTO tblfixedfares VALUES (NULL, **2**, 'le675', 'le115', '11', '1', 'Car');
INSERT INTO tblfixedfares VALUES (NULL, **2**, 'le675', 'le115', '22', '2', 'Car');
```

The database is as follows:

id, **FixedFareId**, ShortPostcodeA, ShortPostcodeB, Fare, DayHalf, VehicleSystemId

id is autoincrement, the fixedfareid needs to be 1 if null, and +1 of the max value of fixedfareid if not null.

Comment: can you post the result of this query, `DESC tblfixedfares`?

Answer (score 2):

change your query like this :

```
          INSERT INTO tblfixedfares (SELECT NULL, IFNULL(MAX(FixedFareId), 0) + 1, '$fieldFrompc', '$fieldTopc', '$fieldDay', '1', 'Car' FROM tblfixedfares);
```

Comment: I've tried this, it still doesn't work. It's not SELECTING the MAX value for FixedFareId, this is why the count is not correct

Comment: Trigger is used when you want to handle table events like update, insert or delete ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html ) so you can add a post/pre data processing

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for:

```
INSERT INTO tblfixedfares SELECT NULL, COALESCE(MAX(FixedFareId),0) + 1, etc..
```

Hence if the MAX of FixedFareId is NULL, it is treated as zero and subsequently '1' is added to it, resulting in '1' if the field is null. (Since MAX(NULL) yields 'NULL').